# Como puedo refactorizar este codigo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tengo un proyecto personal, donde utilizo react con redux, tengo este codigo por ahora todo funciona bien,pero veo que puede mejorarse bastante y asi ahorrar unas lineas. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```js
  const country = props.match.params.code;

 
  const { dataDetailsCountry } = props;
  const { countrytimelinedata } = dataDetailsCountry;

  const title = (countrytimelinedata && countrytimelinedata[0].info.title)
  const code = (countrytimelinedata && countrytimelinedata[0].info.code)

  console.log(title);
  return (
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver es complicado darte una respuesta que satisfaga todos los criterios, te dejo cómo yo lo haría por si te sirve:

```js
const props = { dataDetailsCountry: { countrytimelinedata: [
        { info: {
                title: "title",
                code: "code",
                },
        }
] } };

const { dataDetailsCountry: { countrytimelinedata = [] } } = props;
const [ details = { info: {} } ] = countrytimelinedata;
const { title = "", code = "" } = details.info;

console.log(title);
```